# else condition is always executed even if the if statement is true

Tags: javascript, debugging, if-statement

I am trying forever to fix this code: i have a list and i am searching through the list to find students. Once i don't find a student, an error message should appear. At the moment i have a function who searches the student based on text match. I have an if statement inside the function. When the match is found show student and when not, hide all the students. I created a variable 'found' set to 'true' when the student is found. if this is false the message should be appended.

The problem is that both conditions are being executed it seems so if i put found as being false inside the second condition the error message will display every time.

At the moment i have another if which checks if found was false. the problem is it doesn't recognise that it is false...so confusing. Please see screenshot with the console where you can see that although the student is found, the second condition is executed each time... [screenshot with the console - second condition is always executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUtjr.png)

First condition doesn't execute unless it's true.

Please help as I am trying to investigate this forever and I asked lots of questions here around this issue but with no big results.

Thanks so much,
Alina

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("student-list");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

//add search bar 
$( ".page-header" ).append('<div class="student-search"></div>');
$( ".student-search" ).append('<input id="input-search" placeholder="Search for students..."/><button id="search">Search</button>');

// append to the .page the container div for the error message
$('.page').append('<div class="error"></div>'); 
// append to the error div a p with the error message if student is not found

var found = true;


//myFunction
function myFunction() {  
    var input = document.getElementById("input-search");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i+=1) {  
        var h = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if (h.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) {
            li[i].style.display = ""; 
            console.log('yey found it');
            found = true;
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";   
            console.log('condtion 2');
        }      
      } 
      if (found===false) {
         $('.error').append('<p>"student not found!"</p>');  
      }
    $('.pagination').hide();
}

//myFunction end
$('#search').on('click', function(){
      myFunction();         
});

// when the input is empty return to page 1, empty the error div, show pagination, 

$('#input-search').on('keyup', function() {
 if($(this).val() === '') {
   go_to_page(0);
   $('.pagination').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function is called more than once judging that 'condition 2' got logged 50 times , and the condition isn't satisfied every time,
To make sure that it doesn't reach the else statement even if the code entered the if statement edit the function to be like this:

```
function myFunction() {  
    var input = document.getElementById("input-search");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    found = false
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i+=1) {  
        var h = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if (h.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) {
            li[i].style.display = ""; 
            console.log('yey found it');
            found = true;
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";   
            console.log('condtion 2');
        }      
      } 
      if (found===false) {
         $('.error').append('<p>"student not found!"</p>');  
      }
    $('.pagination').hide();
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
}
```

That way you see how many times the function was being called

Comment: I checked when you click search the function is called just once but right from the start if condition 1 is true the else is being executed as well...

Comment: So there is no '-----' line between 'yey found it' and 'condition 2' in the console?

Comment: No the line only comes after the 'condition 2' .

Comment: The only explanation is that in the loop, some iterations go in the if statement and others go in the else statement

Comment: It seems like it, but how can i stop this?

Comment: if you want the loop to stop after entering the if statement, you can use 'break;'

Comment: If I understand correctly, use it like I used it in the code above and it should work

Comment: It does work, but the problem doing that is it doesn't get to hide the rest of the list items since this is in the else statement.

Comment: I want if there is a match to show the list item/s and hide the rest of the list, else if there is no match hide all list items and show error message.

Comment: And what was happening before adding the break? I think the code did exactly that before adding it

Comment: yes if you look at my screenshot it was working perfect, showing the match and hiding the rest of the list.  But I don't know how to show the error message once there is no match...

Comment: you should set found to false every time the function is called like in the code above that I edited

Comment: found was always true even when no student was found

Comment: that works well, but the again because of the break it doesn't hide the rest of the list. it just seems if and else at the moment work together somehow. i can't break before else. i should have something like do this and this in the first condition and show error in the second....

Comment: @lovefashro remove the break, it shouldn't be there, I told you to add it because I thought you had another problem

Comment: I reedited the code, I think it should work without the break

Comment: it does work: i search first and find a match, all good. i search again, there is no match the error message shows. all good. if i search only the matching students it is all good, if i dont have a match and AFTER i search again a matching student this time the error message remains on the page although there was a match. if i refresh the page each time before i search i have no errors. so yes a bit buggy

Comment: it's because you don't hide it incase found is true, add an else statement that hides it